# scrollIntoView() safari Vue JS fix

Tags: vue.js, iframe, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Using `scrollIntoView()` for Safari iOS and Safari appears to not jump the user to the top of the page. I'm loading a multi-step form into an iFrame of a site.

Every time the user clicks the next step button, the following method is ran:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.stepStart.scrollIntoView()
})
```

What would the solution be to push to the top of the page for Safari

Comment: Is `stepStart` a Vue component or a DOM element? If the former, you'd need to use `this.$refs.stepStart.$el.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: It's a `ref="stepStart"` on a `<div>`

Comment: Any suggestion @StephenThomas

Comment: Not much else to say given the limited information in the original question